# Which query would be better for Paging?

Tags: sql-server, paging

Which query would be better for Paging Query 1 or Query 2

**Query 1:**

```
select CEILING(CONVERT(decimal,Count(*))/@PageSize) as TotalPages FROM  Table
```

**Query 2:**

```
Select (Count(*) + @PageSize - 1)/@PageSize as TotalPages FROM  Table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bases on your sample i'll go for the query 2

But technically speaking they both have the same performance in SQL Server, try executing them and see the execution plan.

Comment: @user3278498 on what basis you chose Jade 's answer .May i understand ?